react-doc-viewer giving CORS error for viewing pdf files
I am using react-doc-viewer to view different file types, all other file types works fine, but the issue occurs when trying with pdf files, the react-doc-viewer itself is hitting the uri provided by azure storage but it gives CORS error, and when i hit the same uri on other tab the files is getting downloaded, i am not understanding if the Cross-origin isn't allowed then why is it letting me download the file from same url and not letting viewer work with it ?
I Simply provided uri and file type to the react-doc-viewer:
                  const docs = [
                  {
                    uri : {My URI From Storage},
                    fileType: 'pdf',
                  },]

                   <DocViewer
                    pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
                    documents={docs}
                    config={{
                        header: {
                            disableHeader: true,
                        },
                    }}
                    style={{ height: '85vh' }}
                />


The Doc Viewer component relies on React PDF internally. React PDF uses fetch to retrieve PDF details from storage sources like S3. However, fetch is subject to CORS restrictions, causing errors if the host is not allowed on the S3 server. You'll need to configure your S3 server to permit access from the host to resolve this issue. You can find more information in this threads:
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/10044#issuecomment-824955082.
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1253#issuecomment-1026095758

@sms Yes i found out the storage was having CORS restrictions, i  white labelled my host and it worked.
